# Meteor with mantra. Cross cutting concerns

Tags: javascript, meteor, jsx, cross-cutting-concerns

I'm developing application in meteor with mantra. This is a routes.jsx of `users` module. I want to be able to use `requireLogin` and `redirectUsers` in other modules' actions and routes. Or in general how do I deal with cross cutting concerns without violating mantra architecture?

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'react-mounter';

import Login from './containers/login';
import Register from './containers/register';
import App from '/client/modules/core/components/app.jsx';

export default function (injectDeps,{FlowRouter,Meteor,LocalState}) {
  let userRoutes = FlowRouter.group({
    prefix:'/user',
    name:'user'
  });

  const AppCtx = injectDeps(App);

  const redirectUsers = () => {
      if(Meteor.userId()){
        const path = LocalState.get('INTERRUPTED_REQUEST_PATH')
          ? LocalState.get('INTERRUPTED_REQUEST_PATH') : '/joke/';
        FlowRouter.go(path);
        return;
      }
  }

  const requireLogin = (path) => {
      if(!Meteor.userId()){
          LocalState.set('INTERRUPTED_REQUEST_PATH',path);
          FlowRouter.go('/user/login');
        return;
      }
  }

  userRoutes.route('/', {
    triggersEnter: [(context,redirect) => {
      if(!Meteor.userId()){
         requireLogin('/user/login');
      }
    }],
    action() {
    }
  });

  userRoutes.route('/login',{
    triggersEnter: [(context,redirect) => {
      redirectUsers();
    }],
    action() {
      mount(AppCtx, { 
        content: () => (<Login />)
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been defining shared functions in `/clients/modules/core/libs/` and using it anywhere. I breaks the encapsulation when you use the function outside `core` module but I haven't found a better way. Let me know if you know one.

Also, redirecting and authenticating in triggersEnter is considered antipattern.

Here is a real life example from my open source Mantra app [Vym](https://vym.io). See there bits:

- https://github.com/vymio/vym/blob/aaa7b97786170ae0a5cad2229e4370744850e261/client/modules/core/containers/home.js#L16
- https://github.com/vymio/vym/blob/master/client/modules/core/libs/auth.js#L4-L14

The repo is available [here](https://github.com/vymio/vym) if you want to see more of it.

You could also use this [reusable auth composer](https://github.com/sungwoncho/meteor-auth) and handle the authentication on the component level.

Comment: Thanks, I think that putting the cross cutting logic in composer function and composing with it wherever required is really good approach.

Comment: But what about action level? For example, every user can view the component but only logged in users can do X and Y